# Why does uint256 variable accept array type input?

Tags: solidity, truffle

I have some question between uint256 type and the array.

There is my Solidity sample Code:

```
contract Test{
  constructor(){ }
  function getValue(uint256 _value) public returns(uint256) {
    return _value;
  }
}
```

I notice that the getValue function can accept array type input.

In order to figure out this problem, I write an unit test case by truffle framework.

And here is my test case:

```
it('test', async function () {
  let value;
  for(let i = 0; i <= 300; i++) {
    await this.Test.getValue.call([i]);
  }
});
```

The test case will be fail when the i is equal to 256.

In basically, the input only accept uint256 type in my case. But it also accept array.

Here is the error message when test case fail:

```
Error: invalid number value (arg="_value", coderType="uint256", value=[256])
```

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Sorry, but why aren't you receiving the array as 
`function getValue(uint256[] _value) public returns(uint256) {` ?

Comment: I don't expect that to receive the array, I just want to receive one uint256 value at first. But I notice that this function can not only receive unit256 but also receive array when I do the test.